# Bash Script Return EmptyString when application running on systemd service

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, service, systemd

I have application FastAPI which I run directly through below command

```
gunicorn app.main:app --workers 4 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0
```

It works fine. Now I serve this app through systemd service

```
[Unit]
Description=To run FX FastAPI backend through gunicorn
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/fx/fx_demo_all_modules/fastapi/
Environment="PATH=/home/fx/fx_demo_all_modules/fastapi/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/fx/fx_demo_all_modules/fastapi/venv/bin/gunicorn app.main:app --workers 4 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Location of service file is `/etc/systemd/system` and also I change the owner from root to fx

The service is also worked fine.

Problem comes when I run bash script from python

```
manufacturer = subprocess.check_output(['/var/www/get-manufacturer.sh'])
```

The Script is below

```
#! /bin/bash
var=$(sudo dmidecode -s system-manufacturer)
echo $var
```

If I run the application direct then it works fine if I run from service it didn't work. Below is journalctl log

```
/var/www/get-manufacturer.sh: line 2: sudo: command not found
```

Advance thanks for the solution.

Comment: Try to change `sudo` to `/usr/bin/sudo` and `dmidecode` to `/usr/sbin/dmidecode`

Comment: try the full path to sudo `/usr/bin/sudo` (run `which sudo` and return that output to check if that is the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `Environment="PATH=/home/fx/fx_demo_all_modules/fastapi/venv/bin"` to below:
`Environment="PATH=/home/fx/fx_demo_all_modules/fastapi/venv/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"`

Comment: Also for gunicorn based app, it is good to add your own gunicorn enviroment details as below:
`EnvironmentFile=/etc/my-app/conf-gunicorn.py`

conf-gunicorn.py could looks like below:


# The number of worker processes for handling requests
workers = 8
# The socket to bind
bind = "localhost:<port>"
# Write access and error info to /var/log
accesslog = errorlog = "/var/log/my-app/gunicorn.log"
capture_output = True